# multiple module error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap']);
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['infinite-scroll']);
```

I want to use the `infinite-scroll` http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html but it seems like I'm doing it the wrong way. How to include the module?

Comment: Arun's answer should do it. Just thought I'd add that it is an error to use the dependency notation more than once for any given module.

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the original list instead of trying to declare a new module

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap', 'infinite-scroll']);
```